# Is a complete metric space a continuum?

Tags: complete-spaces

By definition, a continuum is a compact connected metric space. Is it correct to say that a complete metric space is always compact connected? In other words, can I say that a complete metric space is a continuum? Thanks in advance

Comment: $\mathbb R$ is complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ittay Weiss pointed out, a complete metric space need not be compact: $\mathbb R$ is a counterexample. In fact, the implication works the other way round: all compact metric spaces are complete! (The standard theorem I'm quoting says that a metric space is compact iff it is [totally bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totally_bounded_space#Definition_for_a_metric_space).)

A complete metric space need not be connected either. For example, $[0,1] \cup [2,3]$ is complete (since it is a closed subspace of the complete space $\mathbb R$), but it is not connected.